# Can anyone give a simple code for houghlines using C#? As I got the transform, I want to detect the lines in images

Tags: c#

Can anyone give me a simple code for houghlines in c#? Since I am new to .net, I didn't know how to do hough transform. Then I found the code for Hough transform but I need to detect the lines in images. For that theta and rho value is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using an existing feature extraction library. Some popular ones are AForge.NET and OpenCV.

Pulled off of [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/hough_transformation.html) example documentation:

```
HoughLineTransformation lineTransform = new HoughLineTransformation( );
// apply Hough line transofrm
lineTransform.ProcessImage( sourceImage );
Bitmap houghLineImage = lineTransform.ToBitmap( );
// get lines using relative intensity
HoughLine[] lines = lineTransform.GetLinesByRelativeIntensity( 0.5 );

foreach ( HoughLine line in lines )
{
    // ...
}
```

You can install AForge.NET via the NuGet Package Manager included with Visual Studio. (Google for details.)